# how to make a rand() number become static in every post - wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, post, random

I make scheduled post using `wp_schedule_single_event()`, the value of `post_content` is using `[shortcode]`. I generate random number using `rand()`, and want to put it inside every post.

The problem is, i want to make the random number become permanent/static. So, Every time the post refresh, the number won't change.

Comment: So i'll think you have to store your first rand() value return in post_meta of your post, and when you call your shortcode check if a value exists, if not generate one, if exists use the value store in your post_meta

Comment: don't hesitate to validate the answer bellow

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store your first rand() value return in post_meta of your post, and when you call your shortcode check if a value exists, if not generate one, if exists use the value store in your post_meta